# How-To implement DAO/DTO in Java for Table JOINS?

Tags: java, mysql, join, design-patterns, dao

I have implemented quite a complicated DAO Layer in Java, based on the most excellent BalusC articles, here: http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html

My question is: what is the best way to do Joins in this "pattern"?

In my project, I have done joins with "composite" classes - eg. I have Stage, StageDAO and Node, NodeDAO classes, and litertally joined them to form JOINNodeStage, JOINNodeStageDAO classes.

This doesn't seem very optimal to me - is there a better way?

Many thanks in anticipation!

PS. Is BalusC out there? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if quit understand...  but i think that what you need to do is to have a collection of Stage inside Nodes so you dont need a class for the joins.

You can fetch the collection on every find of the dao or u can make a lazy load requesting it just when u need it.

Hope that's help

Comment: Yeah, with my way, you end up with as many classes as you have possible combinations of joins that you want!